# How can I display local images if I don't know their location before runtime?

Tags: ios, react-native

```
var imageSource = require('./images/test.png')
<Image source={imageSource} style={s.userPic} />
```

That works great, but I need to show local photos just taken with the device (iPad) camera, so I won't know the local file location, stored in "user.imageLoc"...

```
var imageSource = eval("require('" + user.imageLoc + "')")
<Image source={imageSource} style={s.userPic} />
```

But that doesn't work. "Unknown module named (insert file location here)"

How can I display local images if I don't know their file name/address before runtime?

Comment: `<Image source={user.imageLoc} />`

Comment: Yields: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass image source as prop to your component :)

```
<MyCustomImageComponent imageSource={require(user.imageLoc)} />
```

Comment: Didn't work, same issue. "Unknown named module: './images/test.png'

Comment: But thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate you taking a look!

Comment: Try using react-native-fs and get the full path to require it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access photos from your gallery or taken with the camera, maybe the best approach is to use the CameraRoll API from RN. v

This is the documentation: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html

If that doesn't work or it's not what you want, we can try to find other solutions.